# CI Active record not work in Google Chrome?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I write this query in CI.

```
$this->db->select("initiation.*, project.projectname,subproject.subprojectname, concat(employee.firstname,' ',employee.lastname) as 'name'")
                ->from('initiation')
                ->join('project','initiation.projectid=project.id')
                ->join('employee','initiation.leaderid = employee.id')
                ->join('subproject','initiation.subprojectid=subproject.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

It works fine in Firefox, but get this error message in Chrome.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

Any idea please?

Comment: accept someone's answer after you solved your problem. It will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Try with result_array(); Make sure you have autoloaded database library

```
$this->db->select("initiation.*, project.projectname,subproject.subprojectname, concat(employee.firstname,' ',employee.lastname) as 'name'")
                ->from('initiation')
                ->join('project','initiation.projectid=project.id')
                ->join('employee','initiation.leaderid = employee.id')
                ->join('subproject','initiation.subprojectid=subproject.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
return $query->result_array();
} else {
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select("initiation.*, project.projectname,subproject.subprojectname, concat(employee.firstname,' ',employee.lastname) as 'name'")
    ->from('initiation')
    ->join('project','initiation.projectid=project.id')
    ->join('employee','initiation.leaderid = employee.id')
    ->join('subproject','initiation.subprojectid=subproject.id','left');
$query = $this->db->get();
$result = $query->result_array();//changed
return $result;//changed
```